# SPDC entangled photons and orbital angular momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-entanglement

I know that spontaneous parametric down conversion (SPDC) produces entangled photons in the orbital angular momentum (OAM), i.e., for a pump beam with zero OAM,

$ |\psi \rangle = | 0 0 \rangle + | 1 -1 \rangle  + | 2 -2 \rangle + ... $

where the numbers indicate the OAM of the single photons.

Now If I add a spiral phase plate from $0$ to $ 2 \pi$ after the SPDC crystal what will I obtain?

Something like this?

$ |\psi \rangle = | 1 1 \rangle + | 2 0 \rangle  + | 3 -1 \rangle + ... $

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question. However, to get a visual sense of what is being asked, check out the very last page of this 2001 paper by one of Zeilinger's teams: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104070 (The figures are a bit scrambled.)